# Is it possible to star a profile?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Sometimes I find profiles I would like to review in the future.  Is there a way to star/bookmark a profile?

Comment: This kind of goes against the "Its about the post, not the person" concept.

Comment: Also related [A “friends list” on Stack Overflow would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/886/178816)

Comment: There are some apps for that. Like [StackEye - Chrome Extension to follow users and questions on StackExchange sites](http://stackapps.com/questions/4454/)

Answer (score 11):

Yeah - use your browser's bookmark feature:

[image]

Nothing built into the site though. As Bradley noted in the comments, we tend to discourage fixating on specific users.

Comment: "Suspicious characters list"

Comment: "gonzobrains" will get a lot of profile views due to this answer